# Substitution of IndexedBase inside a summation

Tags: sympy, substitution

I'm trying to substitute an IndexedBase inside a summation in sympy.  Outside the summation it works, but inside I'm getting back the expression without the substitution:

```
In [125]: (f, n) = sympy.symbols("f n")

In [126]: foo = sympy.IndexedBase(f)[n]

In [127]: foo.subs(foo, 1)
Out[127]: 1

In [128]: sympy.Sum(foo, (n, 0, 5)).subs(foo, 1)
Out[128]: 
  5       
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   f[n]
  ╱       
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
n = 0
```

Why does the last step not replace `f[n]` by 1, and how do I need to change my code to ensure that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because *n* is a dummy variable and it would change the value of the summation. That is, *.subs( )* should give you the same value as when applied to the expanded summation:

```
In [7]: sympy.Sum(foo, (n, 0, 5)).doit()
Out[7]: f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5]
```

In this expression there is no *f[n]* anymore, as it has been replaced by the respective numerical values. Substitution won't work:

```
In [8]: sympy.Sum(foo, (n, 0, 5)).doit().subs(foo, 1)
Out[8]: f[0] + f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5]
```

Therefore, *.subs()* will ignore matches on variables that are summed over (in this case *n*).

*replace( )* on the other hand doesn't care about value consistency and replaces the matching expression anyway:

```
In [9]: sympy.Sum(foo, (n, 0, 5)).replace(foo, 1)
Out[9]: 
  5    
 ___   
 ╲     
  ╲   1
  ╱    
 ╱     
 ‾‾‾   
n = 0
```

Of course, the resulting value is now different:

```
In [10]: sympy.Sum(foo, (n, 0, 5)).replace(foo, 1).doit()
Out[10]: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use the [`replace` method](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=replace#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) instead:

```
In [129]: sympy.Sum(foo, (n, 0, 5)).replace(foo, 1)
Out[129]: 
  5    
 ___   
 ╲     
  ╲   1
  ╱    
 ╱     
 ‾‾‾   
n = 0
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27953986/974555).